# Checkout offer to order special product once

Tags: magento2, promotions

We are currently on M2.

In order for customers to try new products we would like to promote what we call "checkout offers". In theory a particular product for which the customer can only order 1 item. Once the item is in the cart it should no longer be visible.

The 1 qty restriction can be achieved by using the inventory setting "Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart" and have it set to 1.

However when testing this the "purchase" button remain even though I have 1 item in cart. Which I need to disable in someway. I'm afraid this will be kind of complex with custom code etc. Maybe their are built in support already or some ready made extensions to sort this?

**EDIT**
It actually depend. The promo product will be the same as an "original product" we do have for sale. However for this special price the product should only be available once.

So this could be a scenario:

User A adds product A to cart. When visiting checkout user gets promoted with an offer. Try Product B for only $0.99
User A may only add this product once proceed and pay for everything.

However, if user decided to just purchase Product B they would be asked to pay the full price. So the price of $0.99 is only available at checkout. Hence I'm considering this to be a different SKU.

Comment: I expect that product is for free? Set a minimum order amount then.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clear it up. You have a product which you want to promote. Is this product usually available for purchase, let's say after the customer gets this product for free or at discount, they should be able to place another order, this time paying for it? You want, if you have that specific product in the cart, to not be able to see this product on the frontend?
The easiest way to achieve this, from my understanding, is, as you said, to set the Max Qty to 1. This will not let you add more than 1 item to the cart. And you can add a cart rule, and set up the promotion for this product, and set "Uses per Customer" to 1, so, the customer can get this promo only once.
Please let us know more details.

Comment: See comment above

Comment: I would do it this way:  set a cart rule promotion.
Customer Groups: uncheck NOT LOGGED IN if you have guest checkout.
No Coupon.
Uses per Customer: 1
Add a condition to check for a specific condition, whichever condition you have as a requirement, a different item to be in cart, an amount minimum, etc.
Apply: Fixed amount discount
Discount amount: original price - 0.99
Maximum Qty Discount is Applied To: 1
Apply the rule only to cart items matching the following conditions: add your product.
This rule will apply the discount to 1 item only on checkout, customer gets it only once.